# Как задать размеры Bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap

Необходимо задать размеры Bitmap во фрагменте. Размеры фрагмента известны. Желательно код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Bitmap originalBitmap = ...;
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
    originalBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, false);
```